# Disable auto focus in drawer of Ng Zorro & Angular

Tags: angular, drawer, autofocus, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to disable auto focus first input in Ng Zorro drawer. I know that Ng Zorro modal has a property for disabling the auto focus. But Drawer does not.
I have a very bad solution: I have put a useless input and styled it like this: `<input type="text" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0" />`. Presently it works

If You would have a better solution than mine, Please, share your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added the tab-index property to all my inputs with -1 as value. It's work for me !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you are right. Autofocus does not work after that. But it can not solve my problem(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an element like this;

```
<button class="opacity-0" [attr.cdkFocusInitial]="false"></button>
```

I dug into ng-ant-zorro to see how it was managed, saw the use of Angular Material `[attr.cdkFocusInitial]` so I simply added it and set it to false on a basically invisible element, seems to have fixed the focusing issue for me.

I am using TailwindCSS so opacity-0 applies the style `opacity: 0;`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not work. I know it works for Dailog in Angular Material and it works too in ng zorro modal. I need this implementation for the Ng Zorro Drawer.